# How to format the output string of an Android TextClock?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the hours/minutes one size, and the seconds and am/pm a different size.  I think I need to use setFormat12Hour(CharSequence format), but have not been able to find the correct sequence.  I am currently using something like "HH:mm:ss a". I have seen some spannable example, which seem to work on a static text string, but cannot figure out how to apply it to the TextClock.

Thanks,
Rob

Here is my current code:
        //Set the TextClock format.
        mClockView = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.textClock);

```
    SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString("h:mm");
    SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString("ss");
    SpannableString span3 = new SpannableString(" a");
    span1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.00f), 0, 4, 0);
    span2.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.40f), 0, 2, 0);
    span3.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.20f), 0, 2, 0);

    mClockView.setFormat12Hour((Spanned) (TextUtils.concat(span1, span2, span3)));
```

This gives me "h:mm" as one size, "ss" as another size and "a" as another size.  What I would like to do is put the "ss" on top of the "a" right next to the "h:mm".

Answer (score 0):

Change HH to hh to get 12 hour format on your CharSequence.

```
h == hour am/pm i.e. 1-12
```